# PHP - merge values of arrays where previous array has missing or present but empty values

Tags: php, arrays, merge

How can I merge two arrays:

```
$arr1 = [1 => 'a', 2 => '', 3 => 'c'];
$arr2 = [1 => 'd', 2 => 'e', 3 => 'f'];
```

and get:

```
[1 => 'a', 2 => 'e', 3 => 'c'];
```

I have done it succesfully with:

```
$arr1 = [1 => 'a',           3 => 'c'];
$arr2 = [1 => 'd', 2 => 'e', 3 => 'f'];

$arr1 + $arr2;
```

But, sometimes $arr1 also contains value `2 => ''` which is empty but present and in this case key `2` will not be overwriten by `$arr2`.

Comment: Look at `array_merge`

Comment: Why not `array_filter($arr1) + array_filter($arr2);` ?

Comment: I want empty values to remain if they are present. No value, empty value, non-empty value - I want all of that present in final array.

Comment: Your desired result: `[1 => 'a', 2 => 'e', 3 => 'c'];` doesn't seem to match with your above statement. It looks like instead of a merged array, you want to fill keys with empty values on $arr1.

Is this close to your supposed desired result? -->
`array('a', '', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');`

Comment: @Daan thanks! I realised array_merge does the job (just from other side).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
  $arr1 = array(1 => 'a', 2 => '', 3 => 'c');
  $arr2 = array(1 => 'd', 2 => 'e', 3 => 'f');
  $arr3 = array_filter($arr1) + array_filter($arr2);
  print_r($arr3);
```

Comment: I want to preserve empty value and overwrite with non-empty if present.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr1 = array("a","","c");
$arr2 = array("d","e","f");

$i = 0;
foreach ($arr1 as $value) {
  if($arr1[$i] == "")
           $arr1[$i] = $arr2[$i];
  $i++;
}

print_r($arr1);
```

Here matrices must be equal in dimension and the number of elements